# How can I make Vim not remember a command?

Tags: autocmd, undo-redo

I have set up an autocommand, that makes some changes to the file I'm working on, whenever I save. Everything works nice and dandy, except one thing.

Whenever I save, and press `.` afterwards, or undo some commands with `u`, I also undo whatever was done by the  the save autocommand!

Is there some way to use `execute normal` or a similar command, without saving it to the vim history?

Comment: How does `.` _undo_ it? What's in the autocommand? One destructive solution (you'd lose all undo history in that buffer from prior to the save) might be `setlocal undolevels=-1`, run the command(s), `setlocal undolevels&`. Hopefully someone has something better.

Comment: No and please note, it wouldn't really make sense to disable undo for a specific action. You might be able to use `undojoin` or disable undo completly for a short time, so that vim "forgets" what it needs to undo.

Comment: Disable undo for a short time sounds fine to me

Comment: That's what my comment is about. Setting `'undolevels'` to -1 disables undo. You'll have to live with the possibility of losing any previous undo history for that file, though.